# Express and express-mailer

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to node js and express.  I installed express-mailer using npm with no problems.   From the (mac) command line I generated an express (4.13.1) app with "express".  Per the github instructions I modified app.js and changed:

```
var express = require('express');
```

to

```
var express = require('express')(),
    mailer = require('express-mailer');`
```

but then "node start" crashes with:

```
/Users/gary/mailertest/node_modules/express/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:58
var status = res.statusCode
                 ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined`
```

I launch a node session and I know the `var express = ...` succeeds.   The line that fails is the subsequent:

```
var app = express();
```

I definitely don't understand all the pieces here so I'm not sure how to continue troubleshooting this.

Comment: Where do you define `res`?  There's not enough code here.  Also, you're calling `Express()` even though you define the variable as `express`.

Comment: edit to correct express() vs Express().   res is not in my code.   The express command line tool created the whole skeleton app.   The "hello world" app runs fine unedited.   If I make the single edit to add the mailer, then it crashes.

Comment: Can you please post your full index.js because it's making very little sense as of now. Shortened info: `res` is where you set the data that you respond to a user and you get `req` and `res` after a user has done a get/post etc request.

Comment: **Most probably** you are calling node-mailer outside a `route` or a `middleware`, both of them have access to `req` and `res`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read from your code description:

```
    var express = require('express')(), 
      mailer=require('express-mailer');

    //.. some code here

    var app = express();
```

You should not instantiate two times express, instead you should instantiate express once:

```
    var express = require('express'), 

    //.. some code here

    var app = express(); 
    var mailer = require('express-mailer');
```

So even after you run successfully your example, bear in mind about what it says in [node-mailers documentation](https://github.com/RGBboy/express-mailer#installation):

> Works with Express 3.x.x

And you are working with the express version 4.x, so not sure if this express-mailer library may have some issues with this aspect of express version.

Comment: Of course the problem was my lack of familiarity with certain javascript syntax.  Thanks for the clarification